# risk mongoDb _id and cookie

Tags: security, mongodb, cookies

I would like to know if is there a secure issue id I set the _id of my user in cookie to identify users or it will be better to set a cookie username and an otherone encode pwd

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is absolutely a security risk -- it means that, if a user can discover the `_id` of another user (e.g, if you accidentally display it somewhere), they can log in as that user. Worse yet, the `_id` cannot be changed after the fact, so there's no way to force another session to remotely log out, or to recover from a stolen cookie.

Use sessions for login, not user-specific data.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of a comment, kind of an answer.

The choices presented are both bad; also known as a [Morton's fork](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morton%27s_fork).

1. put userid in a cookie: bad because, as duskwuff said, cookie can be stolen and the id passed back in.  No way to stop it.
2. put username and encrypted password in cookie: bad for exactly the same reasons.

A third option is preferable: send back an encrypted session ID that has a limited lifetime.  Once the server determines that the session is timed out, don't use it anymore.